# Loading file in RAM

Tags: linux, files

I have an application which opens a large file (about 1-2GB) every time it runs.

For development/testing reasons, I need to keep restarting the application, and the 30s-1m wait time to load the file from HDD becomes a bit inconvenient.

Is there a way to put the file in the RAM (and keep it there), so loading would be faster?

Comment: Would a ramdisk be an option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your system has enough RAM, the file should be cached in memory, so it *shouldn’t* be re-read from the drive every time.

You can try to force the issue by copying the file to a `tmpfs` file system, and load it from there. `tmpfs` file systems are RAM-based. Most distributions now use a `tmpfs` for `/tmp`, so copying the file there will work; if you need to, you can `mount` a `tmpfs` yourself somewhere else and copy the file there. However, if memory is short, the contents of a `tmpfs` can be swapped out, so you may end up reading from swap.

Answer (score 1):

The file system *should* already cache the file **if** you have enough RAM.

However, to create a dedicated 2GiB RAM-disk at `/tmp/ramdisk` for the purpose you can do the following:

> ```
> sudo mkdir /tmp/ramdisk
> sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2G myramdisk /tmp/ramdisk
> ```